# Setting guid type for property in ksoap2-andorid request

Tags: android, soap, ksoap

I am developing android app with ksoap2-android library.
I can get and parse some responses, but I can't send particular request, which needs to put property with "guid" type.

The service, which I want to use, says that I don't put the property, though I am sending with String type.
Maybe I need to put it as a "guid" type.

From my poor understandings, there is no way to set type as guid neither ksoap or Java.

I am new to Android, and programming.
Maybe i am asking silly question, but i am straggling with this for few days.
Please somebody give advice and i will be very grateful!

Below is the definition of request which is be public by the service.

```
  <AuthTicket>string</AuthTicket>
  <DicIDList>
    <guid>guid</guid>  // this property is what i can't put!! 
    <guid>guid</guid>
  </DicIDList>
```

I am putting the property like this...

```
    soapObject.addProperty(SearchItem.TAG_AUTH_TICKET, SearchItem.AUTH_TICKET);
    SoapObject dicIdList = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "DicIdList");
    dicIdList.addProperty("guid", item.dicId);
    dicIdList.addProperty("guid", "19553dab-aa51-43bb-9fb7-764153b647ac");
    soapObject.addProperty(SearchItem.TAG_DIC_ID_LIST, dicIdList);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

I had to put namespace every time when i adding a property.

so, i should write like this.

dicIdList.addProperty(NAME, "guid", "19553dab-aa51-43bb-9fb7-764153b647ac");